# Patch applied with system's patch but rejected by git-apply

Tags: git, patch

I'm trying to understand how does git apply unified diffs.

I wrote the following "identity" patch:

```
--- a/js/controllers.js
+++ b/js/controllers.js
@@ -15,3 +15,3 @@
-  '$location',
-  function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
-    doSomething();
+  '$location',
+  function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
+    doSomething();
```

The system's patch command applies this patch with success while git-apply gives the following output:

```
error: patch failed: [...]js/controllers.js:15
error: [...]js/controllers.js: patch does not apply
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patch has no context. `diff` would have included a few unmodified lines before and after the changes as well. From the `git apply` documentation:

> `--unidiff-zero`
>
> By default, git apply expects that the patch being applied is a unified diff with at least one line of context. This provides good safety measures, but breaks down when applying a diff generated with `--unified=0`. To bypass these checks use `--unidiff-zero`.
>
> Note, for the reasons stated above usage of context-free patches is discouraged.